# Sequelize + Express: No database selected

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, mysql2

Junior developer here.

I am trying to test my api. I'm using Node v18, Express v4 and Sequelize v6 on MySQL.

Here is my `config.js`

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, HOST } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  development: {
    "username": DB_USERNAME,
    "password": DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": DB_NAME,
    "host": HOST,
    "dialect": "mysql",
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    }
  },
  staging: {
    "username": DB_USERNAME,
    "password": DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": DB_NAME,
    "host": HOST,
    "dialect": "mysql",
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    }
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

Here is my model `index.js`

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require('../../../config/config.js')[env];


const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database, config.username, config.password, {
        host: config.host,
        dialect:config.dialect,
        operatorsAliases: false,
        pool: {
            max: config.pool.max,
            min: config.pool.min,
            acquire: config.pool.acquire,
            idle: config.pool.idle
        },
        port: 3306
    }
)

sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Database connected `)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`Error: `, err)
    })

const db = {}

db.Sequelize = Sequelize
db.sequelize = sequelize

db.abouts = require('./abouts')(sequelize, DataTypes);
db.clients = require('./clients')(sequelize, DataTypes);
db.address = require('./address')(sequelize, DataTypes);
db.career = require('./career')(sequelize, DataTypes);

module.exports = db
```

It works fine in development. However, on staging it throws "No database selected" [Table schema is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTago.png)

I have checked the documentation and solutions everywhere, none of them work. Migration and seeding work except for this. Variables on `.env` are named correctly, no typos.

Comment: Did you check `DB_NAME` variable value in the code on staging?

Comment: Yes. It was the correct db for the staging process.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not on the ORM but on the database.
We solved it by redeploying it with another database connection.